# Electron error 'The procedure entry point DiscardVirtualMemory could not be locted in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll'

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have an application in Electron version 25.3.0 by packaging it with the electron-builder with this command `$ electron-packager . migration-agenda-day --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --out=dist/ --overwrite`, this command generates a package with an .exe file, when trying to run this .exe in windows server 2008 R2 I get the error 'The procedure entry point DiscardVirtualMemory could not be locted in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll', I was already investigating but I can't find the solution, could you help me..

[image]

Comment: Seems only present in Windows 8.1 / Windows Server 2012 R2 and later (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-discardvirtualmemory). Exe is build on that level. Is your os at that level?

Comment: I generate everything from my Windows 10 machine but I am trying to run the .exe on Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit

Comment: I don't know this electron-builder. Perhaps it can be built it for a lesser Windows version like Windows Server 2008. That version does not support DiscardVirtualMemory.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Windows Server 2008 R2 is not supported by Electron v25. Two quotes from Electron's documentation:

> Electron 23 no longer supports Windows 7/8/8.1. Electron follows the planned Chromium deprecation policy, which will deprecate Windows 7/8/8.1 , as well as Windows Server 2012 and 2012 R2 support in Chromium 109 (read more here).

https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-23-0#dropping-windows-7881-support

and

> Electron will end support of Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 beginning in Electron 23. [...] Electron 22 will be the last Electron major version to support Windows versions older than 10.

See https://www.electronjs.org/blog/windows-7-to-8-1-deprecation-notice

---

I see two options for you:

1. Downgrade to Electron v22
2. Upgrade your runtime environment (newer windows server version)